# View chart cursor only in the chart's portion in areachart of Recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am trying to use rechart's areachart. There is an option to enable cursor which will show the points plotted on the graph on hover. However I want to show that cursor only uptill where the chart's portion lies and not above that. Is there anyway to achieve this?

[image: Want to achieve this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using a custom component for cursor. First, I had to store the position of the active dot in a state variable and then pass this variable as a prop to custom cursor component and then draw the line uptil the active dot.

```
const CustomCursor = (props) => {
  const { points, activeDotPos } = props;

  const startingPoint = points[0];
  const endingPoint = points[1];

  const [x1, y1] = [startingPoint.x, activeDotPos.y + 10]; // adding 10 to y to prevent cursor from overlapping with active dot
  const [x2, y2] = [endingPoint.x, endingPoint.y];

  return (
    <svg x1={x1} y1={y1} x2={x2} y2={y2}>
      <line
        x1={x1}
        y1={y1}
        x2={x2}
        y2={y2}
        stroke={"#B5B5B5"}
        strokeWidth={1}
        strokeDasharray={"10 10"}
      />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

[Example Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-area-chart-recharts-xo3bts?file=/src/AreaChart.jsx:3397-3964)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it really helped in resolving the issue  I was facing!